# how to create a third column by manipulating two columns in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have two columns that look like this:

| Name | Apple | Orange. |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2. | 1 |
| A | 3. | 1 |
| A | . 1. | 1 |
| B | . 2 | 4. |
| B | . 3. | 2 |

Now I wanted to take the sum of two columns for each row and divide each value by the sum and convert it into a percentage and display it in the third.
Now expected result is

| Name | Apple | Orange. | . Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2. | 1 | 66.67% Apple, 33.33% Orange. |
| A | 3. | 1 | 75.00% Apple, 25.00% Orange. |
| A | . 1. | 1 | 50.00% Apple, 50.00% Orange. |
| B | . 2 | 4. | 33.33% Apple, 66.67% Orange. |
| B | . 3. | 2 | 60.00% Apple, 40.00% Orange. |

Here is the SQL code used in postgres

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    Name varchar(255),
    Apple int,
    Orange int
);

INSERT INTO Persons (Name, Apple, Orange)
VALUES ('A', '2', '1'), 
        ('A', '3', '1'),
        ('A', '1', '1'),
        ('B', '2', '4'),
        ('B', '3', '2'
       );

select *
from Persons;
```

Comment: Please share with us on what you've tried. Also, tag only one rdbms, thank you

Comment: please pick just one of mysql, postgres, or snowflake; they are different things and can have different answers.

Comment: Do you just want the new column to appear in the result set, or do you want to update the schema of the table to include the new column?

Comment: @StewartMacdonald how to query the desired result if I want to update the schema of the table to include the new column? Would you mind helping me with that?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only **one** tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: @BadCoder first of all, you must have a column for it. Secondly, do update with condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try in this way.
The answer below is for mysql or sql.

```
SELECT name, apple, orange,
CONCAT(ROUND(CAST((apple * 100.0 / (apple+orange)) AS FLOAT), 2), '% Apple, ',
       ROUND(CAST((orange * 100.0 / (apple+orange)) AS FLOAT), 2), '% Orange')
AS result
FROM Persons;
```

In order to get the percentage, you need to get the sum first, thus, I use 'apple+orange'

Check out this [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ptdfDgBnonXq1gPfFw8EDp/0)

Comment: Thank you for the response but I am getting an error in postgres. Would you mind helping me with this.

**ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying * numeric
LINE 2: CONCAT(ROUND(CAST(((Apple*100.0) / (Apple+Orange)) AS FLOAT)...
                                 ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.**

Comment: I was able to rectify the error. Thank you for your help.
**CONCAT(ROUND(CAST(((Apple::float*100.0) / (Apple::float+Orange::float)) AS numeric), 2), '% Apple, ', ROUND(CAST(((Orange::float * 100.0) / (Apple::float+Orange::float)) AS numeric), 2), '% Orange') AS result**

Comment: @BadCoder this is an example of why you need to tag only the database you are actually using and why you need to provide your table schema, not just data.

Comment: yes, I agree with @ysth.